# illegal_argument_exception while creating elasticsearch mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-mapping

I am trying to stream logs from logstash to elasticsearch (5.5.0). I am using filebeat to send logs to logstash.

I have not defined any index; it is defined automatically (say "test1") when data is pushed for the first time.

Now, I want to create another index ("test2") so that I can manage field data types. For that, I got the mappings for test1. Updated the index name. And did PUT call for test2 with this data. However, it fails with following result:

`ubuntu@elasticsearch:~$ curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/test2?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'@/tmp/mappings_test.json'

```
{
  "error" : {
  "root_cause" : [
    {
      "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason" : "unknown setting [index.test2.mappings.log.properties.@timestamp.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"
    }
  ],
  "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
  "reason" : "unknown setting [index.test2.mappings.log.properties.@timestamp.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

`

Following is the excerpt of the json which I am using. 
`

```
{
  "test2" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "log" : {
        "properties" : {
          "@timestamp" : {
             "type" : "date"
           },
        "@version" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
         }
      },
        "accept_date" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
....
```

`

I modified index name only. Rest of the content is same as mapping of test1 index.

Any help is appreciated on how to create this new index by updating types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove `test2` on the second line and have only `mappings`:

```
PUT test2
{
    "mappings" : {              <---- this needs to be at the top level
      "log" : {
        "properties" : {
          "@timestamp" : {
             "type" : "date"
           },
        "@version" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
         }
      },
        "accept_date" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
....
```